# Async agnostic higher order functions

Tags: asynchronous, f#, higher-order-functions

Suppose we have a library that provides a higher order function `applyTest`.

Can this be used with an asynchronous function `asyncFunction` while retaining the benefits of asynchronous code?

Can the library be designed to better support asynchronous applications without specifically providing an asynchronous version?

```
let applyTest f =
    f 2 > 0

let syncFunction x =
    x - 1

let asyncFunction x =
    x - 2 |> async.Return

async {
    let a = applyTest syncFunction
    let b = applyTest (asyncFunction >> Async.RunSynchronously)
    printfn "a = %b, b = %b" a b
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to provide a separate async version if you didn't want to lose strong type checking, or running async computations synchronously like in your examples. Both of these things should be avoided as much as possible.

If you wanted to avoid repetition of the actual testing part (`f 2 > 0`) you could split this out into a function that passes the parameter `2` to the function and a function to check the value is greater than zero:

```
// LIBRARY CODE

let checkValue x = x > 0

// This function is generic so it can return a value or an async value
// (int -> 'a) -> 'a
let runTestFunction f = f 2

// (int -> int) -> bool
let applyTest f = f |> runTestFunction |> checkValue

// (int -> Async<int>) -> Async<bool>
let applyTestAsync f = async {
    let! value = runTestFunction f // use let! to await the value
    return checkValue value }

// USAGE

let syncFunction x = x - 1
let asyncFunction x = x - 2 |> async.Return

async {
    let a = applyTest syncFunction
    let! b = applyTestAsync asyncFunction // use let! to await the test result
    printfn "a = %b, b = %b" a b
}
```

Another option would be to use overloaded methods. This builds on the functions defined above:

```
type Test =
    static member Apply f = applyTest f
    static member Apply f = applyTestAsync f

// USAGE

async {
    let a = Test.Apply syncFunction
    let! b = Test.Apply asyncFunction // We still need to consume this differently with a let!
    printfn "a = %b, b = %b" a b
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try a different approach for my architecture. I've discovered a number of interesting blogs that explore this area, starting with an equivalent issue for [IO in Haskell](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/18/functional-architecture-is-ports-and-adapters/). Although some of the business logic spills into outer layers, it may actually simplify my overall design.